# Drupal 8 Node Add/Edit form is showing WSOD

Tags: php, forms, error-handling, drupal-8

I am working on a Drupal 8 site.

Node Add/Edit page is showing blank.

Following are steps taken to find out error:

1. Recent Log Messages (No Error logged)
2. PHP Error Log file (No Error logged)
3. Set memory_limit to -1 and other PHP settings related to
   memory in case memory is exhausted.
4. Uninstalled Custom modules.
5. Changed site theme from custom theme to core theme.

NOTE: All other forms are working(block add/edit, etc..)

Please let me know if any of SO people faced this issue before.

Comment: Any SO expert here?

Comment: What about Apache/Nginx or the server error logs? Do you have any hooks related to node? Used exit() / die() somewhere in those hooks...

Comment: You can try setup debug mode and check the issues. The link below how to setup debug mode - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127182/how-do-i-enable-developer-debug-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed my problem ourselves.

We found no error in modules and themes.

So, we decided to restore and old backup.

After the back up was restored, the functionality: Node Add/Edit started working.